# Python3 - CSV - Add Rows with namedtuple

Tags: python-3.x, csv

Trying to make a method to add new rows following the interface bellow:

```
def row_add(self, **rowtoadd)
```

I don't see how, if I define my columns like:

```
stuff1, stuff2, stuff3
```

I can get a **namedtuple to sort itself in the correct order of columns names.

So far, I've tried (here table = the filepath we're editing, containing the csv we need):

```
def row_add(self, **rowtoadd):
  if os.path.isfile(self.table):
     with open(self.table, 'a') as csvfile:
        csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
        csvwriter.writerow(rowtoadd)
```

But the namedtuple is not converted into a row, only the name of variable are.
ex:

```
row_add(stuff1="hello1", stuff2="hello2", stuff3="hello3")
cat ./my_file.csv -> stuff1, stuff2, stuff3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
csvwriter.writerow(rowtoadd[x] for x in sorted(rowtoadd.keys()))
```

The issue is two-fold:

1. 'rowtoadd' is a `dict` object. The order of the keys of a dict is not upheld in python.
2. When you `writerow(rowtoadd)`, the default iterator in a `dict` is over the keys, which is why your csv file is getting the keys rather than the values.

In my line of code above, `sorted(rowtoadd.keys())` sorts the keys of the dict, so that they are in a predictable order (alphabetical). `rowtoadd[x] for x in ...` makes it a comprehension which provides an ordered list of the values you'd like to print into the file.

A key thing to understand here is that the `csvwriter` is not aware of the files preexisting structure. It doesn't know what order the keys should be in. You need to specify that order somehow. In this case, I specified the order alphabetically, but you may need to do it differently.

If you don't know the names of the fields beforehand, you could use positional arguments to keep the order of the fields. Positional arguments become a `tuple`, which is an ordered type in python:

```
def row_add(self, *row):
  if os.path.isfile(self.table):
     with open(self.table, 'a') as csvfile:
        csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
        csvwriter.writerow(row)
```

This solution relies on the fact that the caller provides the arguments in the correct order.